# Create list of values sorted by a column during group by

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` like this:

```
product_id          raised_at       qty             value           ETA                     order_id        shipment_id     shipment_stage
696                 2021-01-25      1               0.000           2021-04-02              987             9797            created
696                 2021-03-08      2               0.000           2021-04-05              193             1455            created
279                 2021-03-08      8               0.000           2021-04-05              195             1457            ordered
539                 2021-01-13      1               0.000           2021-04-27              959             3523            shipped
553                 2021-01-13      1               0.000           2021-04-27              959             3523            shipped
...
913                 2021-06-22      10              633.600         2021-11-05              761             6317            ordered
921                 2021-06-22      40              1,872.000       2021-11-05              761             6317            shipped
767                 2021-06-22      10              201.600         2021-11-05              761             6317            created
773                 2021-06-22      20              820.800         2021-11-05              761             6317            created
609                 2021-05-05      40              2,563.200       2022-08-17              523             4395            ordered
```

I am trying to have one `df` which would have the following columns - I separate the `final_df` into 3 for visibility.

`df1` - which is grouped by `product_id` and has the earliest `ETA` followed by other columns

```
product_id          ETA_earliest        order_id_earliest       qty_earliest           value_earliest             shipment_id_earliest        shipment_stage_earliest
696                 2021-04-02          987                     1                      0.000                      9797                        created
279                 2021-04-05          195                     8                      0.000                      1457                        ordered
...
```

`df2` - which is grouped by `product_id` and has the latest `ETA` followed by other columns

```
product_id          ETA_latest          order_id_latest         qty_latest            value_latest                shipment_id_latest          shipment_stage_earliest
696                 2021-04-05          193                     2                     0.000                       1455                        created
279                 2021-04-05          195                     8                     0.000                       1457                        ordered
...
```

`df3` - which is grouped by `product_id` and has all values per `product_id` in a list sorted by `ETA` along with other columns. So that the first value of `ETA` corresponds to the value of the same row of other columns. For example `product_id = 696` has two entries, so:
`[2021-04-02, 2021-04-05]` would be the `ETA` value and `[987, 193]` would be `order_id` and I would know that `order_id = 193` has `ETA` of `2021-04-05` as they both are the second values in the list.

```
product_id          ETA_all                         order_id_all            qty_all   value_all                   shipment_id_all         shipment_stage_earliest
696                 [2021-04-05, 2021-04-02]        [987, 193]              [1, 2]    [0.000, 0.000]              [9797, 1455]            [created, created]
279                 [2021-04-05]                    [195]                   [8]       [0.000 ]                    [1457]                  [ordered]
...
```

What I've tried:

`df1 = df.loc[df.groupby('product_id').ETA.idxmin()]`

It works as well as

`df2 = df.loc[df.groupby('product_id').ETA.idxmax()]`

But I don't how I should create the `df3` so that each value would be sorted and I can map them back together based on their index in the list.

**UPDATE**

After using

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values('ETA')
df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]
df = df.groupby('product_id').agg(list).reset_index()
```

```
df[df.product_id == 3721]

product_id              qty             value           ETA                                         order_id    shipment_id     shipment_stage
3721                    [3, 1]          [999.0, 333.0]  [2021-06-24 00:00:00, 2021-08-02 00:00:00]  [521, 725]  [283, 021]      [created, ordered]
```

But when I filter the original `df` I get more than 2 values:

```
df[df.product_id == 3721] # original
 
product_id  qty              value                  ETA                order_id     shipment_id     shipment_stage
3721        3                999.000                2021-06-24         521          283             created
3721        1                333.000                2021-06-24         521          281             created
3721        1                333.000                2021-06-24         549          285             created
3721        12               3,996.000              2021-06-24         553          279             created
3721        3                999.000                2021-06-24         601          287             created
3721        1                333.000                2021-06-24         629          291             created
3721        2                666.000                2021-07-05         629          289             ordered
3721        1                333.000                2021-07-12         681          677             ordered
3721        1                333.000                2021-07-26         697          773             ordered
3721        1                333.000                2021-08-02         725          021             ordered
```

So it looks like it only has the `min` and `max` `ETA` dates. I expect it to have 10 items in the `df3` list as there are 10 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need filter only minimal and maximal rows per groups use:

```
#join together and sorting
df31 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values('ETA')
#remove duplicates by index
df31 = df31[~df31.index.duplicated()]
#aggregate list
df31 = df31.groupby('product_id').agg(list)
```

---

If need aggregate all values sorted by `ETA` use:

```
df3 = df.sort_values('ETA').groupby('product_id').agg(list)
```

Comment: But this only works if there are only 2 or less `product_id`, so the list would only have a max of 2 values, what if there are 6 rows with the same `product_id`?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - Can you test now?

Comment: I updated my question with an example after using your code, it seems I only get 2 values, the min and the max of `ETA`.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - I got it, so need only `df2 = df.sort_values('ETA').groupby('product_id').agg(list)` ?

Comment: So in total there are 3 `dfs`, one with `ETA = min(ETA)`, one with `ETA = max(ETA)` and one where all `ETA` are in a sorted list and all values are sorted in a list by `ETA` too. Right now I have `df1` and `df2` how I need it, I need `df3` with all values in a list. In my update I show that `product_id = 3721` has 10 rows in the original `df` but in your example my `df3` only has 2 items in a list for `product_id = 3721`, I want it to have all 10 items.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - So need second part of answer?

Comment: Your last update `df3 = df.sort_values('ETA').groupby('product_id').agg(list)` provides what I need, thank you.